# javascript function - using a parameter inside of quotes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use a function to hide a list of elements and then show the element that I want visible by inputting the element's id as the function's parameter

```
function newSelect(showThis){
$("#main-menu").hide();
$(" + showThis + ").show();
```

}

How can I put the parameter variable into the " " without having it be parsed as a string?

Comment: *hopes this isn't a dupe* - probably is, but I couldn't find it. Might be a misinformed question. JS newbie

Comment: Why do you think you need the quotes at all?

Comment: @JasonP Do I not? I thought that since the syntax included them, the parameter needed to be used inside of them

Comment: The quotes are the syntax for specifying a string literal. The quotes are not a part of the _value_ of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `showThis` is a string you can use `$('#' + showThis).show();`

Comment: Thanks guys! Newbie ftl

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the quotes at all. You can simply use `showThis` directly:

```
$(showThis).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can try one of the following:

- If `showThis` is just a piece of `HTML` code, do: `$(showThis)`
- If `showThis` represents a CSS `class`, do: `$('.' + showThis)`
- If `showThis` represents an element `id`, do: `$('#' + showThis)`
- If `showThis` represents an element `name`, do: `$("name='" + showThis + "'")`